# Random walk on a pentagon touching all vertices

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk, combinatorics-on-words

a particle is confined to jump from one vertex of a pentagon to an adjacent one every second. As a function of the number of jumps $n$, what is the number of walks that eventually touch every vertex?
I have tried setting up a recurrence relation or representing the walk as a lattice path to no avail...

Comment: It seems like the "one second" and "random" and "eventually" parts make the problem more complicated than necessary.  Do you want the number of walks of length $n$ that contain every vertex?  Equivalently, the number of words of length $n$ on $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ that contain every "letter" and with all pairs of adjacent letters differing by $1 \pmod 5$?

Comment: Yeah I guess the wording of the problem is quite confusing. Like you said, what I want is the walks of length $n$ that contain every vertex and that can only move to adjacent vertices each time.

Comment: This is directly related to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723147/lattice-paths-with-maximum-vertical-height) which asks for the number of paths that do not visit all vertices. This one is OEIS: [A027558](https://oeis.org/A027558)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider a "state" of the system to consist of the number of vertices visited so far and an indicator of whether the current vertex is adjacent to an unvisited vertex.  Thus you start at $(1,Yes)$, and the other possible states are $(2,Yes)$, $(3,Yes)$, $(3,No)$, $(4,Yes)$, $(4,No)$ and $(5,No)$.

EDIT: Let $M_{ij}$ be the number of choices the walker can make in state $i$ that lead to state $j$.  Thus in state $(1,Yes)$, there are two choices which lead to state $(2,Yes)$, so $M_{12} = 2$ and all other $M_{1j}=0$.
You want $(M^n)_{17}$.

Comment: I don't see how this helps...

Comment: @LorenzoCatani hint #2: how many paths are there in a given state at a given time?

Comment: Trying to set up a recursion, I have realised that $(M^n)_{17} = 2(M^{n-1})_{17}+${number of paths that get to state $(4, Yes)$ in exactly $n$ steps} however I haven't managed to find an expression for the second part. Am I moving in the right direction?