# Counting Dyck-like Paths?

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

Dyck paths count sequences of $n$ 1's and -1's s.t no sub-sequence from the left side has a negative sum. Suppose we instead have the restriction that no sub-sequence from the left should have sum greater than $U$($0\leq U \leq n$) or less than $L$($-n\leq L \leq 0$). Is there a known way to decompose this counting problem?

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3559986/variant-of-bertrand-ballot-problem-limiting-the-difference/3561677?r=SearchResults&s=6|0.0000#3561677). In particular, you can use my formula with $m=n$, $a=U+1$, $b=-L+1$.