# Generating function for recurrence with dependence between indices for paths in lattice

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Is there a general approach for finding a generating function for a recurrence which has a dependence between its indices?

As an example consider the paths with north- and east-steps in a 2d-lattice contained in a band of width $T$ going from (0,0) to (m,n), the recurrence relation is then (I hope)

\begin{align*}
C(m,n) = \begin{cases} 1\quad &\text{if }n= m = 0\\
0 &  \text{if } |m-n| > T\text{ or }m<0\text{ or }n<0 \\
C(m-1,n) + C(m,n-1)\quad& \text{else.}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

I know that there are combinatorial approaches to solve this problem but was wondering whether there is a general method using generating functions for this case directly (comparable to the case without the 2nd condition)? Where can I learn about it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not know of a generating function solution, but you can determine $C(m,n)$ using https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3561677