# Expression for the sum of a row in a truncated Pascal's 5d simplex

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

A 5d Pascal's simplex is the 5d equivalent of a 2d Pascal's triangle. Each point is calculated as the sum of 5 predecessors.

In Pascal's triangle any row specified by the number of generations $g$ can be seen as counting up the number of different walks that lead there from the top. The equivalent in the 5d simplex is the 4-dimensional layer also defined by a generation $g$ which is a positive integer. The value at each point in that 4-dimensional layer at generation $g$ corresponds to the number of walks to that point. The maximum is near the diagonal between the 5 dimensions. The sum of all the values of each layer is $5^g$.

We want to constrain the maximum number of steps away from this central diagonal to create a truncated 5d Pascal's simplex. So at point $(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5)$ at generation $g=t_1+t_2+t_3+t_4+t_5$ if any difference $\mathrm{abs}(t_a - t_b) > s$ (for $t_a, t_b \in \{t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5\}$) then the value is taken to be zero. (If there is a better way of specifying the distance from the diagonal, we can use that.)

I have asked the equivalent question about the 2d Pascal's triangle [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499676/expression-for-the-sum-of-a-row-in-a-truncated-pascals-triangle-or-simplex) and received an excellent solution by Mike Earnest that I would have been unlikely to arrive at by myself.