# Expression for the sum of a row in a truncated Pascal's pyramid

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

This is a substantial rewrite of the question.

Pascal's pyramid is the 3d equivalent of Pascal's triangle.

Each point $P(x,y,z)$ at positive integer coordinates $x,y,z$ is defined by $P(x,y,z)=P(x-1,y,z)+P(x,y-1,z)+P(x,y,z-1)$

When any coordinate is zero it simplifies to Pascal's triangle.

The value at each point P(x,y,z) is the number of walk paths from P(0,0,0) to P(x,y,z) and can be directly calculated using the trinomial numbers.
$P(x,y,z)=\frac{(x+y+z)!}{x!y!z!}$

A layer at generation $g$ are the points that satisfy $x+y+z=g$

The sum of all the values at generation $g$ is $3^g$

Now we would like to investigate the sum of a layer of a truncated pyramid.

First we need a metric to define distance from the central diagonal. We can use

$D(x,y,z)=\text{Max}( |x-y|, |y-z|, |z-x|)$

Here are the values for $D$ for the first 7 layers:
[image: distance from centre line metric]

We can define the truncated Pyramid with distance $s$ to have a value of $0$ at $x,y,z$ if $D(x,y,z)>s$

For example here is the distance metric for layer 12 where all points with a distance > 4 are marked in red.

[image: layer 12 of pascals pyramid with distance metric]

We are looking for an expression that depends on $s$ that gives the sum of a layer at generation $g$ in a truncated Pascal's pyramid.

The value of a point at x,y,z of a Pyramid with truncation distance s is:

$$
\mathrm{P}(x, y, z, s) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if D(x,y,z) > s}  \\
    1 & \text{if 2 or 3 coords of x,y,z are 0} \\
    {P}(x,y-1,z)+{P}(x,y,z-1) & \text{if x=0} \\
    {P}(x-1,y,z)+{P}(x,y,z-1) & \text{if y=0} \\
    {P}(x-1,y,z)+{P}(x,y-1,z) & \text{if z=0} \\
    {P}(x-1,y,z)+{P}(x,y-1,z)+{P}(x,y,z-1) & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Here is some Mathematica code that calculates the sum of a layer recursively:

```
"Global`*" // Remove // Quiet (* start with a clean slate *)

(* the distance metric d *)
d[x_, y_, z_] := Max[Abs[x - y], Abs[y - z], Abs[z - x]]

(* the value of a point x,y,z in pascals pyramid with truncation s *)
p[x_, y_, z_, s_] :=
 If[d[x, y, z] > s, 0,
  If[(x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) ||
    (x != 0 && y == 0 && z == 0) ||
    (x == 0 && y != 0 && z == 0) ||
    (x == 0 && y == 0 && z != 0), 1,
   If[x == 0, p[x, y - 1, z, s] + p[x, y, z - 1, s],
    If[y == 0, p[x - 1, y, z, s] + p[x, y, z - 1, s],
     If[z == 0, p[x - 1, y, z, s] + p[x, y - 1, z, s],
      p[x - 1, y, z, s] + p[x, y - 1, z, s] + p[x, y, z - 1, s]
      ]]]]]

(* the sum of a layer *)
sumtpp[g_, s_] := Module[{sum = 0, x, y, z},
  For[x = 0, x <= g, x++, For[y = 0, y <= g - x, y++, z = g - x - y;
    sum += p[x, y, z, s]]];
  sum]
```

This is useful for debugging, but too slow for large values, so we need a closed form expression for the sum.

The equivalent question for Pascal's triangle has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499676/expression-for-the-sum-of-a-row-in-a-truncated-pascals-triangle-or-simplex/4500102#4500102)

Comment: "Each point $P(x,y,z)$ at positive integer coordinates $x,y,z$ is defined by $P(x,y,z)=P(x-1,y,z)+P(x,y-1,z)+P(z,y,z-1)$" : Is this a $\color{red}{\text{misprint?}}$  Should it instead be "...$P(x,y,z)=P(x-1,y,z)+P(x,y-1,z)+P(\color{red}{x},y,z-1)$"?

Comment: Indeed. Thanks. I fixed the typo.

Comment: I believe the problem can be solved just like in the 2d version that you link:

(1) First interpret the sum as the number of paths that do not cross some particular planes. (2) Then use the reflection principle to interpret the sum as the number of paths that end on some particular locations in your piramid.
(3) Finally sum over the entries in these locations.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: ChatGPT does not reason.

Comment: It does try to explain what it is doing when you ask it to.

Comment: ChatGPT does not "try" anything.  It is a language model, it constructs something that resembles the next line in a conversation based on probabilistic models and a large database; there is not process of truth-seeking or reasoning or anything like that taking place.  It is a very sophisticated version of 10,000 monkeys working at typewriters.

Comment: Six months ago @Gutiérrez gave you a very concrete suggestion of something to try; did you ever try it?

Comment: I do not understand the suggestion by @Gutiérrez and I have asked for more information to get me started. I am very motivated to find a solution to this question.

Comment: This morning I had a several hours long conversation with chatGPT4. It looks very much like it is reasoning to me.

Comment: Guierrez's suggestion is extremely concrete, if you have sat with it for six months but never written down a single line of mathematics inspired by it then I don't see how you can honestly say you are motivated to solve this question.  (I will not return to this question, there is no need to respond to me.)

Comment: @xen It looks like it's reasoning because it's trained on texts that look like they're reasoning. If you ask it to come up with novel reasoning, you will see it fail miserably. This of course requires the user to be able to distinguish novel reasoning from rote reproduction, and to be able to distinguish coherent reasoning from nonsensical jumbles of words.

Comment: I removed chatGPTs attempts as they seem to distract from the question.